# jQuery undefined object

Tags: jquery

I writing this, because it's driving me crazy, and I don't know how its possible:

My code

```
var categories = new Array(length);
    for (i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {categories[i] = new Array (2);}
    $(".lang-box").each(function(i) {
      if( i < categories.length) {categories[i][0] = $(this).attr('name');categories[i][1] = $(this).val();}
    });
```

How is it possible if I do:

```
console.log(categories.lenght);
```

I get "undefined", but if I do

```
console.log(categories);
```

I get:

```
[ ["pl","fwer"],["en",""]]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: maybe because it's : `categories.length` <- That's an error !

Comment: thx, I think I'm overworked. Thanks again

Comment: please take the additional time to check your spelling and grammar, not only in your Questions, but also in your code. It will alleviate a lot of your issues.

Comment: Close the question, your typo is'nt really helpful to others in any way!

Comment: How can I close it? Sorry but I'm new in stack...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix. If you change

```
console.log(categories.lenght);
```

... to ...

```
console.log(categories.length);
```

it should work fine.

Comment: As above, thanks,  I think I'm overworked. Topic is to close:)

Answer (score 2):

You mistyped length.

Use this:
`console.log(categories.length);`

Comment: Holy crap, that's some observational skills! +1